# Android: How to set the ImageView src from string?

Tags: android

I am very beginner in java, please help. I have an android app source code. My default imageView is like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag_logo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/global_keyline_s"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/flag_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

I need to translate my app in some country, and I need to set dynamically the app title and the flag icon.

I have string resources and already translated:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My App Name</string>
    <string name="flag_icon">@drawable/flag_icon</string>
    ...
</resources>
```

In ImageVeiw, can I change:

`android:src="@drawable/flag_icon"` to `android:src="@string/flag_icon"` ?

When I test this script to an emulator it is ok, but when I try to generate to signed apk I got error:

```
Error:(4) Error: Unexpected resource reference type; expected value of type @string/ [ReferenceType]
```

I've been looking for this issue but have not yet found, please help. thanks.

Comment: I got a question. WHY ?

Comment: You can't change the imageview src to string src. Imageview src is nothing but the imagefile.

Comment: android:src="@drawable/flag_icon"  is an integer value , and you are calling an string value , the Question is WHY ?

Comment: Maybe there is a solution?

Comment: `In ImageVeiw, can I change: android:src="@drawable/flag_icon" to android:src="@string/flag_icon" ?` **NO**. In facts, it gives you an error: `Unexpected resource reference type`. What you can do instead, is using the resource **name** instead of its **id** (which is useful in some limited cases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your approach is a bad idea.

You can localize a drawable too. I think this is the better approach for changing images when localizing your app.

Answer (score 0):

In ImageVeiw, can I change:

> android:src="@drawable/flag_icon" to android:src="@string/flag_icon" ?

No you cant. What `@drawable/flag_icon` means is that the drawable `flag_icon` is located int the `drawable` folder(s). Unless you have a folder with the name 
`string`, that path is invalid

Answer (score 0):

As far as localization is concerned, only some specific res folders can be localized. More information about it [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html).

For drawable you should use something like `drawable-[language code]-r[capitalized localization code]`.

And, your approach won't work (read *isn't working*) because of data value mismatch. `@drawable` returns `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @glethien suggested. I would use localized drawables - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

So you put your image in drawable-hdpi and drawable-de-hdpi and based on device language it will take appropriate resource.